# Is there an Opera turbo feature available for Ubuntu?

Tags: opera

Windows and other versions have an Opera turbo feature which enables the user to compress the data and thus speed up the browsing experience.

Is there an Opera turbo feature available for Ubuntu? If yes, then how to enable this feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Opera turbo feature is avaiable in Ubuntu, as well. To enable it, press `Alt + F10` to summon Menubar and Navigate to `File`. There tick on the `Opera Turbo.`